# Usins scss to select all in @for

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible to select all the outcomes and print them into a CSS line?

My main goal is to make this dynamic so if the $columns is switched to 12 or 8 I still want them to be on one line.

As you can see in the second block of code-- .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 is being printed twice but I only want it to be printed once at the top.

I was possibly looking at another way to write this but I want to keep this as simple as possible.

```
.col-1 {
  float: left;
}

$columns: 4;

@for $col-width from 1 through $columns {
   .col-#{$col-width} {
     width: ((100 / $columns) * $col-width) * 1%;
     @extend .col-1;
   }
 }
```

So this code above will show the following. My issue right now is that all .col(s) are being printed twice. I want it to only show once. What would be the way to only make it @extend once or is their a better option?

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: just to clarify - what exactly do you want the final CSS to be in this 4-column case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [placeholder selector](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors) which can then be extended like given below. Placeholder selectors are selectors that have a `%` in front and such selectors + their rules exist only in the Sass file. This block itself wouldn't be present in the compiled CSS file, only ***the selectors that extend these placeholder will get the properties*** listed within the placeholder selector and so won't unnecessarily add up stuff into your CSS. And since the placeholder selector's rules are never getting modified by the `@for` loop you wouldn't end up with the problem explained in the other answer also.

```css
%float-left {
  float: left;
}
$columns: 4;
@for $col-width from 1 through $columns {
   .col-#{$col-width} {
     width: ((100 / $columns) * $col-width) * 1%;
     @extend %float-left;
   }
}
```

Below is how the compiled CSS would look like:

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 {
  float: left;
}
.col-1 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because col-1 is going through the loop **first**, it's going to have its width defined first (at 100%). After the first iteration of the loop, it will look like:

```
.col-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Subsequent iterations through the loop will try to extend whatever is **currently** in `.col-1`, which **includes** the width of 100%.

Why not simply get rid of the `@extend` and define the float in the loop itself?:

```
$columns: 4;

@for $col-width from 1 through $columns {
   .col-#{$col-width} {
     width: ((100 / $columns) * $col-width) * 1%;
     float: left;
   }
}
```

That way column 1 will still get its 100% width, but the other columns won't ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know I can do it that way but does it make sense to have "float:left" written multiple times?   I wanted to save some lines by having them all under one .css line

Answer (score 0):

You could target all column classes with a wildcard attribute selector

```
// target all classes containing "col-" 
[class*="col-"]{ float: left; }    

$columns: 4;
@for $col-width from 1 through $columns {
  .col-#{$col-width} {
    width: 100% / $columns * $col-width;
  }
}
```

CSS output:

```
[class*="col-"] { float: left; }
.col-1 { width: 25%; }
.col-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-3 { width: 75%; }
.col-4 { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Yes, but one always has to be careful while using these wildcard attribute selectors. For example, this selector would now select an element whose class is `not-a-col-1` etc also.

Comment: very valid point harry. this does seem to be a decent solution but can run into naming convention issues down the line.

Comment: Yes @user3803699 This is a nice option but implementation can become tricky if not careful.

Comment: IMO you have enough options to avoid naming conflicts – e.g. child selector   .grid > [class*="col-"], making naming less general [class*="grid-column-"] and by using :not(.class-something) instead of .not-class-something :-)